Pooled Cross Section Lags in R
I have pooled cross section data of different states at different points in time. I'm trying to see how weather events during crops' growing period affected how the crops are currently priced. To do so, I would like to lag my precipitation variable by 1 month, 2 months, and 3 months and add these new variables to df . My current df looks like this:
df <- data.frame(
  states = c("MA", "MA", "NH", "NY"), 
  dates = lubridate::ymd(c("2021-05-27", "2021-05-25", "2021-05-28", "2021-05-24")), 
  price = c(1.30, 1.28, 1.40, 3),
  precipitation = c(0.5, 1.7, 1.5, 2)
)

I have complete time series data on precipitation for each state that was used in df to match the precipitation with the given dates:
ts <- data.frame(
  state = c("NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA"), 
  date = lubridate::ymd(c("2021-03-24", "2021-03-25", "2021-03-26", "2021-03-27", "2021-03-28", "2021-04-24", "2021-04-25", "2021-04-26", "2021-04-27", "2021-04-28", "2021-03-24", "2021-03-25", "2021-03-26", "2021-03-27", "2021-03-28", "2021-04-24", "2021-04-25", "2021-04-26", "2021-04-27", "2021-04-28", "2021-03-24", "2021-03-25", "2021-03-26", "2021-03-27", "2021-03-28", "2021-04-24", "2021-04-25", "2021-04-26", "2021-04-27", "2021-04-28")),
  precip = c(0.5, 0.2, 2, 4.5, 3, 0.7, 0.3, 1, 0.9, 2, 2, 0.3, 2.5, 2.6, 3.1, 2.1, 3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.7, 2.3, 2.1, 6, 3.8, 3.6, 1, 1.3, 2.1, 3.4, 7)
)

I'd like to lag the dates in df by 1, 2, and 3  months, then look back to the ts dataset and match the current date with the precipitation from the month(s) prior. This might be worded poorly but it would look something like this for the one month and two month lags:
df$precip_1<-c("3.4","1.3","0.7","0.7")
df$precip_2<-c("2.6","0.3","3","2.3")

I tried df$precip_1<- lag(as.xts(df$precipitaion),k=1), but don't actually think this is correct since it's not time-series data. I was thinking of creating new variables with the lagged dates and matching those up to precip directly, then adding it to df . I've never worked with lags before so any help would be appreciated!

@MrFlick I updated it with a reproducible example (I think)! I'm new to R so I'm not quite sure if this is what you meant

I would consider using the lunridate package for this. It allows you to handle dates in a very robust way.
Here is my attempt:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat <- data.frame(Date = c("05/27/21", "05/13/21", "04/27/21", "04/27/21"),
                  State = c("MA", "MA", "MA", "CT"), Price = c(1.3, 1.28, 1, 6),
                  Precipitation = c(0.5, 1.7, 9000, 2))


dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date), #convert to lubridate
         lag = Date %m-% months(1)) %>% #laggs by one month, you can change it to any other number of months or other units too
  left_join(., select(., Price, Date, State), by = join_by(lag == Date, State == State), suffix = c("", "_Lagged")) %>%  #use a left join to match based on the Date - Lagged Date as well as the state, if you need more parameters just add them to join by.
  select(-lag)

dat
        Date State Price Precipitation Price_Lagged
1 2021-05-27    MA  1.30           0.5            1
2 2021-05-13    MA  1.28           1.7           NA
3 2021-04-27    MA  1.00        9000.0           NA
4 2021-04-27    CT  6.00           2.0           NA

First we transform to a Date object with the mdy() function. Then we subtract the month with the %m-% operator. Then we use a left join to match up our lagged dates with the original dates making sure that we are also looking in the correct state (Basically we are merging the data frame with its own copy here, there is a probably a cleaner way to do this with mutate or something but I am not sure how). The suffix argument just determines what the columns from each dataframe will be called. Both of the select() calls are just to clean up and not strictly necessary. If there is no corresponding data for any given date left_join() will just insert an NA.

A good way to go about this would be to change the dates to match the row you want to join to and then do a proper merge. For example
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  left_join(transmute(ts, dates=date+months(1), states=state, precip_1=precip)) %>% 
  left_join(transmute(ts, dates=date+months(2), states=state, precip_2=precip))

This returns
  states      dates price precipitation precip_1 precip_2
1     MA 2021-05-27  1.30           0.5      3.4      2.6
2     MA 2021-05-25  1.28           1.7      1.3      0.3
3     NH 2021-05-28  1.40           1.5      0.7      3.0
4     NY 2021-05-24  3.00           2.0      0.7      2.3

